# Using ZeroClipboard with GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I'm trying to use ZeroClipboard for my project, however it seems the samples provided are mostly about "*Copy to*" clipboard, what is I need the other way around "Copy from" method.

Anyone can share some code ideas on how to implement this?

**Code:**

```
public static native String getPastedText()/*-{
    var clip = new $wnd.ZeroClipboard.Client();

}-*/;
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you _can't_ read clipboard data using ZeroClipboard. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14821210/139010

Comment: Matt, I wonder why a site I saw can do this. I am not sure which library is it but looking at the page I can see ZeroClipboard.js

Comment: I'm going to have to give this one a `[citation-needed]`. Link, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this just using a default browser installation. And this is really a security requirement.

If this would be possible, can you imagine how much data could be stoled just using javascript?